# trouble referencing keys in a hashmap in R

Tags: r, hash, hashmap

I'm using the "hash" library for R to create a hashmap. But I'm having trouble referencing the keys properly:

```
library(hash)
myhash <-hash()
.set(myhash, "10", "abcd")
myhash$"10" # result is "abcd" as expected
foo <- "10"
myhash$foo # result is null -- was expecting "abcd"
```

How can I identify a key in the hash using a variable (e.g. foo, as used above)? I'm building/accessing the hash in a for loop, and I need to be able to able to refer to a key (and corresponding value) using variables rather than the exact key name ("10").

Apologies if this is very basic. I'm new to R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either single or double bracket notation:

```
myhash[[foo]]
myhash[foo]
```

From the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/index.html):

> Convenient access is provided by: hash, $, [ and [[ and their corresponding replacement methods.

Comment: I tried that -- I get "Error in myhash[[10]] : wrong arguments for subsetting an environment." Thanks, though.

Comment: @lost No, that should be working.  Does `hash["10"]` work for you?

Comment: Oh, yes, it looks like it is now (myhash[[foo]] works). Thanks!

Comment: done! It was saying I had to wait 5 mins first. Thanks again!